# How to Search and Match 2 input fields values in Json file and if match found return 3rd Key Value from same json object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a 2 inputs fields where the user will enter Pickup and Delivery area name.When user finish with 2nd input (delivery or pickup - no sequence) I want to initiate a process where both input values are searched from JSON file and if the match for both inputs is found show relevant price. I am able to capture values on both inputs but I need a method to compare them to JSON file and on successful match show price. a method defined in constructor giving me all the objects in Json file.

NOTE. FIND MATCH PROCESS WILL NOT START WITH CLICK, Rather it will start with (change) of value.

**Template**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="pickupSuburb" (change)="onSelectedSuburb($event)" placeholder=" Pickup Suburb Here"   [(ngModel)]="pickupSuburb"  >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input list="suburb" class="form-control" id="deliverySuburb" (change)="onSelectedSuburb($event)" placeholder=" Delivery Suburb Here" [(ngModel)]="deliverySuburb" >
</div>
```

**Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sending',
  templateUrl: './sending.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sending.component.css'],
  providers: [SuburbsService, AutoCompleteSuburbs, CapitalizePipe ],
})

export class SendingComponent implements OnInit {
  priceList = [];

  constructor(private elm: ElementRef, private http: Http) {
    http.get('./assets/zoneRates.json').subscribe(response => {
      this.priceList = response.json();
    })
  }

  ngOnInit () {}

  public onSelectedSuburb(event) {
    const pickupArray = this.elm.nativeElement.querySelector('#pickupSuburb').value.slice(1).slice(-3);
    const deliveryArray = this.elm.nativeElement.querySelector('#deliverySuburb').value.slice(1).slice(-3);}
```

**Json Sample**

```
[{
    "pickup": "SYD",
    "delivery": "QC4",
    "weight": "25",
    "price": "6.25"
  }, {
    "pickup": "SYD",
    "delivery": "QC6",
    "weight": "25",
    "price": "6.25"
  }, {
    "pickup": "SYD",
    "delivery": "QC7",
    "weight": "25",
    "price": "6.25"
  }, {
    "pickup": "SYD",
    "delivery": "ADL",
    "weight": "25",
    "price": "6.25"
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OnChanges lifecycle hook and search through the array of products using array.prototype.find. I don't see anywhere that you declare the form so I'm assuming you're using reactive forms. I suggest switching to dynamic forms (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) as it will make getting the values easier.

My answer is going to assume you make this switch and have both `pickupInput` and `deliveryAreaInput` properties declared in your component which are bound to the associated inputs on your form. If you need to stick with reactiveForms you'll have to get these values some other way.

```
export class sendingComponent implements onChanges, onInit {
  private pickupInput: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required); // You may need different validation than this.
  private deliveryAreaInput: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required); // again your validation may differ.

  /**
   * Checks if either pickupInput or deliveryAreaInput are in the changes object.
   * If either key is included pass both values to the searchJson method and store the response in a match property
   * If match is truthy show the price
   * @param {SimpleChanges} changes
   */ 
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.pickupInput || changes.delieveryAreaInput) {
      const match: any = this.searchJson(this.pickupInput.value, this.deliveryAreaInput.value);
      if (match) {
        this.showPrice = true; // Use this with an ngIf in your template
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Use Array.prototype.find to search through the priceList array for any products that have a matching pickup and delivery area.
   * Array.prototype.find returns either the matching value or undefined if no matches are found.
   * @param {string} pickup
   * @param {string} deliveryArea
   * @return {?} either the matching value or undefined
   */
  private searchJson(pickUp: string, deliveryArea: string): any {
    return this.priceList.find(price => {
      return price.pickup === pickUp && price.delivery === deliveryArea;
    });
  }
}
```

I would be concerned about doing this search on change though. This is going to cause the entire product catalog to be searched on each key press, which if the catalog is long will be noticeably slow. A better solution would be to introduce a button or do the search on focus out instead of changes (although that will require the user to focus out obviously).